# Run phpMyAdmin without SSL/HTTPS

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have just clones phpMyAdmin from git to `/var/www/`.

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/phpmyadmin;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name phpmyadmin.local;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

}

it's saying:

`There is a mismatch between HTTPS indicated on the server and client. This can lead to a non working phpMyAdmin or a security risk. Please fix your server configuration to indicate HTTPS properly.`

I want to run it without SSL.

I don't have the file `config.inc.php` , but I've `config.sample.inc.php` in the main directory `phpmyadmin/` and in this file there is no line `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = false;`

copied `phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php` to `phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`, tried writing these lines one by one

```
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ForceSSL'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['control_ssl'] = false;
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://phpmyadmin.local/';
```

but still same error message!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the sample config file to config.inc.php and put there the settings you want.

Comment: Downvoted. SO is for *answers*, not *links to answers*.

Comment: My post contained the answer plus a link to prove the answer.